# How to remove end tag in jade

Tags: html, node.js, pug

Ok so I have

```
        #main
            form(action="/raspored", method=post)
                label(for="polaziste") Polaziste 
                input(type="list", id="polaziste")
                datalist#polaziste
                    for pol,i in popis
                        option(value = pol)
```

and my datalist doesn't show the options right because (I think) in html5 you are not always allowed to have end tags and this code makes

```
  <option value="-----"></option>
```

In jade reference it says "Jade also knows which elements are self closing:"
but it seems like it doesn't. How do i specify that I do not want to have end tags?

Comment: What entries are preset in `popis`? Is it an array of strings, or objects?

Comment: Popis is an array of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the syntax error in my datalist.
It should be:

```
  input(list="dolaziste", name="dolaziste")
```

and not:

```
  input(type="list", id="polaziste")
```

As for the end tag problem, fixing the code above made things allright withoud meddling with end tags any further

Answer (score 0):

`<option>` is only self-closing under specific circumstances, as documented on MDN (although stackoverflow does not allow a link to that page).

> The start tag is mandatory. The end tag is optional if this element is immediately followed by another  element or an , or if the parent element has no more content.

So probably jade takes the will-always-work approach and closes the option element.

The right thing to do is say "OK, that makes sense" and move on with your life. However, if you feel so inclined, check out [the self-closing.js module from jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/lib/self-closing.js). You could inject `'option'` in there and it would probably behave as you hope.

Comment: This seems like a very sloppy hack. I was hoping for a simple solution

Comment: Yes indeed. Just trying to answer the question and encourage reading source code.

Comment: I did what you told me to do but still no change. It seems like the issue isn't in the code but somewhere else

Comment: Are you using chrome dev tools "inspect element"? They will automatically inject closing tags there. Make sure you are really looking at the raw HTML your server sends.

Comment: I was looking at the inspect element :/

Answer (score 0):

You can mix some html in your jade; Can you try this, and see if it works as you expect?

```
#main
  form(action="/raspored", method=post)
    label(for="polaziste") Polaziste
    input(type="list", id="polaziste")
    datalist#polaziste
      for pol,i in popis
        <option value="#{pol}">
```

Such inline usage of arbitrary html in jade has been [documented](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/tree/0.33.0#html). Wondering why it's not working for you.

Let's give it another try;

```
datalist#polaziste
  each pol in popis
    <option value="#{pol}">
```

Comment: still getting <option value="-----"></option>

Comment: I am using `jade@0.35.0` in `express@3.4.6`. I'm getting html as `<datalist id="polaziste"><option value="test"><option value="dent"><option value="bent"></datalist>`. I'm amused seeing it work. Which version of `jade` are you working with?

Comment: Works as advertised for me as well.

Comment: "version": "0.35.0", :/
EDIT: my express is 3.00 tho, ill update it

Comment: I updated express and it's still not working as expected. What bugs me is why would it automaticly add end tag if im manually entering html? Am I making some other strange mistake? Any ideas?

Comment: Not related to browser for sure, browser receives what gets compiled by node server. Maybe not related, but which version of node? I'm running `v0.10.21`.

Comment: Same. I have some interesting new info. I found in jade documentiation   mentioning of self closing tags and tried to use them.

option/
results in 
<option></option>

(which definitely shouldn't happen) How strange...

Comment: Have updated my answer, have a look and do go through inline html usage in jade docs, link included.